# Stern-Volmer plot and calculation of rate constant for quenching

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, photochemistry

I did an experiment irradiating benzophenone in UV light and worked out the rate constant for the reaction. Then I repeated the experiment using various concentrations of a quencher and worked out their respective rate constants. Now I need to calculate the rate constant for quenching $k_\mathrm{q}$ using a Stern-Volmer plot. How would I do this?

The equation I have used before for the Stern-Volmer relationship is:

$$\frac{1}{I_\mathrm{f}} = \frac{1}{I_\mathrm{abs}}\left(1 + \frac{k_\mathrm{q}[\ce{Q}]}{k_\mathrm{lum}}\right)$$

where the *x*-axis is $[\ce{Q}]$, the concentration of the quencher, and the *y*-axis is $1/I_\mathrm{f}$, and to work out $k_\mathrm{q}$ you calculate the gradient/*y*-intercept = $k_\mathrm{q}/k_\mathrm{lum}$.

I think I would plot a graph of concentration of quencher $[\ce{Q}]$ on the $x$-axis against 1/rate constant on the y axis. But how would I work out $k_\mathrm{q}$?

Answer (score 5):

Benzophenone is a notorious case where prompt fluorescence, phosphorescence and delayed fluorescence can mix. Have a look at *Modern Molecular Photochemistry* by N.J. Turro for some general information and [*Prompt and delayed fluorescence from benzophenone*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(72)87176-8) by 
R.E. Brown and L.A. Singer for the original reference.

\[
\begin{align*}
\ce{BP &->[h\nu]\ ^{1}BP^{\ast}}\\ 
\ce{^{1}BP^{\ast} &-> BP + h\nu'\quad &(prompt\ fluorescence)}\\
\ce{^{1}BP^{\ast} &->[ISC]\ ^{3}BP^{\ast} &(intersystem\ crossing)}\\
\ce{^{3}BP^{\ast} &-> BP + h\nu''\quad &(phosphorscence)}\\
\ce{^{3}BP^{\ast} &->\ ^{1}BP^{\ast} &(repopulation\ of\ S_1)}\\
\ce{^{1}BP^{\ast} &-> BP + h\nu'\quad &(delayed\ fluorescence)}\\
\end{align*}
\]

Let's ignore all this (for a moment).

Fluorescence quenching, i.e the observed decrease of fluorescence intensity in the presence of a quencher, may occcur through two different pathways:

#### Static fluorescence quenching

In this case, **formation of a ground state complex between the fluorophore $\ce{F}$ a quencher $\ce{Q}$** decreases the concentration of $\ce{F}$, hence the concentration of the excited state $\ce{^1F^{\ast}}$ and the fluorescence intensity. **This has no impact on the fluorescence lifetimes!** These are the same in the absence ($\tau_0$) and presence ($\tau$) of a quencher.

\[
\frac{\tau_0}{\tau} = 1
\]

#### Dynamic fluorescence quenching

Here, **quenching occurs from the excited state $\ce{^1F^{\ast}}$**. With other words, the presence of a quencher introduces an additional, non-radiative pathway for the deactivation of the excited singlet state. Consequently, **the fluorescence lifetime $\tau$ is shortened!**

Let's try to derive the *Stern-Volmer* equation and see if that leads to some insights:

(*You probably know all of this already, but I'm just in the mood...*)

In an experiment on dynamic fluorescence quenching, the following processes and their rate constants have to be considered:

\[
\begin{align*}
\ce{F + h\nu &->[k_{abs}]\ ^1F^{\ast}\quad &\mathrm{(excitation)} } \\
\ce{^1F^{\ast} &->[k_{ic}]\ F + heat\quad &(internal\ conversion)}\\
\ce{^1F^{\ast} &->[k_{f}]\ F + h\nu'\quad &(fluorescence)}\\
\ce{^1F^{\ast} + Q &->[k_{q}]\ F + Q'\quad &(quenching)}\\
\end{align*}
\]

The fluorescence quantum yield $\Phi$ is given as the quotient of emitted ($I_{em}$) and absorbed ($I_{abs}$) photons:

\[
\Phi = \frac{I_{em}}{I_{abs}}
\]

The number of emitted photons depends on the concentration of the fluorophore in its excited singlet state $\ce{^1F^{\ast}}$ and the rate constant $k_{f}$:

\[
I_{em} = k_{f}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}]
\]

The number of absorbed photons depends on the concentration of the fluorophore $\ce{F}$ and the rate constant $k_{abs}$:

\[
I_{abs} = k_{abs}\cdot[F]
\]

The rate of absorption processes is difficult to measure, they're bloody fast. Fortunately, we don't have to! **Under steady-state conditions, population of the excited singlet state and its deactivation balances out.**

Consequently, we can express $I_{abs}$ as:

\[
I_{abs} = k_{f}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}] + k_{ic}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}] +k_{q}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}]\cdot[Q]
\]

The expression for the fluorescence quantum yield thus is:

\[
\begin{align*}
\Phi &= \frac{k_{f}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}]}{k_{f}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}] + k_{ic}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}] +k_{q}\cdot[^1F^{\ast}]\cdot[Q]}\\
&= \color{\red}{\frac{k_{f}}{k_{f} + k_{ic} +k_{q}\cdot[Q]}}
\end{align*}
\]

The latter is pretty convenient since we don't have to think about the pesky $[^1F^{\ast}]$ anymore! **YAY!**

If we do perform a fluorescence measurement in the absence of the quencher,  $[\ce{Q}] = 0$, $\Phi_0$, the fluorescence quantum yield under this condition is:

\[
\Phi_0= \frac{k_{f}}{k_{f} + k_{ic}}
\]

The effect of a quencher $\ce{Q}$ on the fluorescence is expressed as:

\[
\begin{align*}
\color{red}{\frac{\Phi_0}{\Phi}} &= \frac{k_{f}}{k_{f} + k_{ic}} \cdot \frac{k_{f} + k_{ic} +k_{q}\cdot[Q]}{k_{f}}\\
&= \color{\red}{1+ \frac{k_{q}\cdot[Q]}{k_{f} + k_{ic}}}
\end{align*}
\]

Too bad that we don't know all these rate constants and using just a steady-state spectrometer, we won't be able to measure them! And for a lab chemist, there's too much stuff in the equation anyway! **Bummer!**

But we can argue about what influences the **fluorescence lifetimes**, which, btw, can be measured!

Lifetimes are pretty much the inverse of the (sum of the) rate constants.

Without the quencher, the fluorescence lifetime $\tau_0$ is:

\[
\tau_0 = \frac{1}{k_{f} + k_{ic}}
\]

In the presence of a quencher, the fluorescence lifetime $\tau$ is:

\[
\tau = \frac{1}{k_{q}\cdot[Q] + k_{f} + k_{ic}}
\]

If we plug that in again and rearrange a bit, we get:

\[
\begin{align*}
\frac{\Phi_0}{\Phi} &= 1 + \tau_0\cdot k_q\cdot[\ce{Q}]\\
&= 1+ {K_{SV}}\cdot[\ce{Q}]
\end{align*}
\]

**We name $K_{SV}$ the Stern-Volmer constant!**

#### Summary

1. Plotting $\frac{\Phi_0}{\Phi}$ or the quotient of the areas of the fluorescence spectra vs the concentration of the quencher should give a straight line, that cuts the $y$ axis at 1.
2. The slope of the curve is the Stern-Volmer constant $K_{SV}$.
3. The real rate constant $k_q$ for the reaction of the excited state $\ce{^1F^{\ast}}$ with the quencher can only be obtained from $K_{SV}$ if the fluorescence lifetime $\tau_0$ has been obtained from a **time-resolved fluorescence measurement**!

Answer (score 0):

If you plot such a graph you should obtain a straight line with some slope $a$ and intercept $b$: $y=ax+b$. You can see that also Stern Volmer relation is a linear function (of concentration). Thus, $k_q$ can be calculated by equating value of slope you obtained ($a$) to $k_q/klum$. Such procedure is simple and important to understand as can be used to determine many quantities which occur in linear equations.

Comment: I don't know what klum is. Is there a way to work it out?

Comment: I find that the commonly used definition of quantum yield as $\Phi = I_{em}/I_{abs} $ is not very intuitive. It is easier to realise that the yield is the $\Phi =$ (rate of fluorescence)/(sum of rate for all other processes) which leads directly to the first equation above in red.